# How go I get a reference to a cell in an array knowing only its value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column array with the following values in my sheet: 11, 15, 5, 7, 2. I want to get a reference to the cell which contains the value 15. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is A2:A13 here is a formula that will get you the reference to the cell with a value of 15...

INDEX(A2:A13, MATCH(15, A2:A13))